# Passing object from VC1 to NSMutableArray in VC2 that is in a separate tab?

Tags: ios

So i have 2 ViewControllers, each is in its own tab.  What is the best way to pass object from VC1 to an NSMutableArray in VC2, that is again, in a separate tab?  I'm not segueing or instantiating any VC.

I've tried this but it crashes with an "unrecognized selector sent to instance" error

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

SPTSavedTrack* trackSelected = self.SPOTUserSavedTracks[indexPath.row];

SPOCVC* spocVC = self.tabBarController.viewControllers[1];
[[spocVC SPOCTrackList]addObject: trackSelected];
```

Thanks!

Comment: is your VC2  a navigation controller?

Comment: it's not.  they're all just uiviewcontrollers

Comment: here is the declaration for my SPOTTrackList in SPOCVC: @property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray* SPOCTrackList;

Comment: Can you provide the full error?

Comment: 2015-01-29 14:04:03.982 spoc1.0[32463:2232254] -[SpotifyTracksVC SPOCTrackList]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f9953d33840
2015-01-29 14:04:03.985 spoc1.0[32463:2232254] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[SpotifyTracksVC SPOCTrackList]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f9953d33840'

Comment: apparently  self.tabBarController.viewControllers[1] is kind of class SpotifyTracksVC and not SPOCVC. Maybe you don't ask for the right tab

Comment: Oh Wow.  haha.  You're right.  I forgot I had embedded a navigation controller for SPOCVC.  No wonder I kept trying all the indexes and none of it would work!! THANK YOU.

Answer (score 0):

in my older apps I've passed objects around using the AppDelegate methods:

```
 AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[appDelegate.arrayname addObject:@"object"];
```

then accessed this shared array from whichever view controller needs it.

Your way, if your target VC has been loaded and array initialised? then i'd expect

```
[spocVC.SPOCTrackList addObject:trackSelected];
```

to work.

Comment: SPOCVC is loaded and SPOCTrackList is initialized.  :/